# How to convert charater to HH:MM:SS, even if we have more than 24h?

Tags: r

I have a datatable in R with some values of time in hours, minutes and seconds. This values are recognized as character and I want to convert them to time.

I've tried with the following functions, but I obtain the same results.

```r
as.ITime(eventlog.dt$Duration)
as.difftime(eventlog.dt$Duration, units = "hours")
as.POSIXct(eventlog.dt$Duration, format = "%T")
```

If my data is this(character format):

```r
12:45:12  72:56:12  05:13:36  162:14:12
```

I obtain:

```r
12:45:12  NA  05:13:36  NA
```

I want to obtain this(time format):

```r
12:45:12  72:56:12  05:13:36  162:14:12
```

Comment: is it possible to convert to hours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The required format can only be a `character` class.  If we need a time class, it needs to be converted properly

```
library(lubridate)
seconds_to_period(period_to_seconds(hms(v1)))
#[1] "12H 45M 12S"    "3d 0H 56M 12S"  "5H 13M 36S"     "6d 18H 14M 12S"
```

If this needs to be converted to hours alone, convert to seconds and then divide by 3600

```
round(period_to_seconds(hms(v1))/3600)
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("12:45:12",  "72:56:12",  "05:13:36",  "162:14:12")
```

Comment: Couldn't you do `as.period(seconds_to_period(period_to_seconds(hms(dates))), "hours")`?

Comment: @Matt you can do that, but the OP wanted to have in a certain format